# Are SPNs specific to Windows and Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, openldap, kerberos, spn

Are Service Principle Names specific to Active Directory on Windows?  Or do they exist in Linux OpenLDAP / Kerberos KDC servers too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're a Kerberos thing.  [MIT Kerberos has them](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.11/doc/admin/princ_dns.html).

I'd have to google other implementations to see if they have them, too.

Answer (score 2):

The term Service Principal Name (SPN), as capitalized, is currently specific to Microsoft Windows, but the general concept of service or server principal names  and conventions defined as part of the [Kerberos Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120#section-6.2.1).